# Cannot go from child route to parent - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a list of routes here which is a top navigation. When I click each item it goes to that route.
Once I'm in a child route and clicked one of the top Navigation it adds the path from the route I have without clearing the route.

> example
>
> /api  > from this route I can go anywhere
>
> /api/id > but from here if I clicked `/api` Link to top nav it changes to `/api/id/api`

App.jsx

```
  <BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Navigation />
    <Switch>

    <Route path="/apis" exact component={SwagUI}/>
    <Route path="/myaccount" exact component={MyAccount}/>
    <Route path="/myapps" exact component={MyApps}/>
    <Route path="/apis/:id" component={SwaggerAPI} />

    </Switch>

</div>    
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Navigation.jsx

```
    <ul class="navbar pull-right">
        <NavLink exact to="admindashboard"><li>Admin Dashboard</li></NavLink>
        <NavLink exact to="apis"><li>APIs</li></NavLink>
        <NavLink exact to="general"><li>General info</li></NavLink>
        <NavLink exact to="contactus"><li>Contact</li></NavLink>
        <NavLink exact to="myapps"><li>My Apps</li></NavLink>
        <NavLink exact to="faqs"><li>FAQs</li></NavLink>
        <NavLink exact to="notification"><li>Notifications</li></NavLink>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the NavLinks `to` attribute should begin with a slash to define it as a path rather than a sub route.

Not able to test right now to confirm tho.